# How to add/delete Apache2 balancer-members without restart

Tags: apache2, load-balancing, mod-proxy-balancer

I want to know, if there is a way to add/delete Apache2 mod_proxy_balancer balancer-members without doing a full restart of apache, so that the existing connections dont't get interrupted?

if i just update the members in the equal vhost-file and do a soft-restart via

```
service apache2 reload
```

apache wont apply the changes made. The provided `balancer-manager` directive and web backend allows to modify the parameters of the particular blanacer-member (e.g. loadfactor) without an restart, but its not possible to add new or delete existing members in this way.

Comment: I have a similar question. Can we add/delete additional members using http://<proxy_host>/<balancer_url> without doing a restart.

Comment: the balancer-manager does not offer functionality to add new members, its only possible to enable/disable existing ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, due to some infrequent problems regarding `apache` and `mod_proxy_balancer` (see https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44736 for more details) i did a little workaround:

first of all filling up the balancer worker configuration with placeholders an setting loadfactor to "1", e.g.:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
   BalancerMember http://www.cmgm.info/virtual/1/  loadfactor=1
   BalancerMember http://www.cmgm.info/virtual/2/  loadfactor=1
   BalancerMember http://www.cmgm.info/virtual/3/  loadfactor=1
   BalancerMember http://www.cmgm.info/virtual/4/  loadfactor=1
   BalancerMember http://www.cmgm.info/virtual/5/  loadfactor=1
   ...
   BalancerMember http://www.cmgm.info/virtual/n/  loadfactor=1
</Proxy>
```

then `mod_rewrite` is used to dynamically assign the placeholders to real balancer memebers, e.g.:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^1/(.*)$ http://www.worker1.de/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^2/(.*)$ http://www.worker2.de/$1 [P]
...
RewriteRule ^n/(.*)$ http://www.workern.de/$1 [P]
```

adding, deleteing, enabling, disabling and setting the loadfactor of each (virtual) member is done by accessing the `balancer-manager` webinterface.

to sum up, `mod_proxy_balancer` can be dynamicall modified programmatically using this workaround.

Comment: Suppose we wanna implement our own lbmethod, can we programmatically add/remove new worker?